# Mathematical misunderstanding of Work-Potential Energy Theorem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, definition

This is a relatively basic question, but I don't understand why it is the case. This is from my dynamics book and is mainly a mathematical misunderstanding.

$$
\ dU = F\cos\theta ds 
$$

Which means the integral should be:

$$
\int_{u_1}^{u_2}dU = \int_{s_1}^{s_2}F\cos\theta ds 
$$

Therefore:

$$
U_2 - U_1 = \int_{s_1}^{s_2}F\cos\theta ds 
$$

However, the book says it is:

$$
U_{1-2} = \int_{s_1}^{s_2}F\cos\theta ds 
$$

I understand why it should be $ U_1 - U_2$ for conservation of energy reasons, but I don't see it in the math... *This way we can say the sum of initial energy (PE,KE,etc.) is equal to the sum of final energy (PE,KE,etc.)*.

Am I missing something somewhere!? The book does not give any hints to this (as far as i can tell). I've posted the most basic portion, but everything else is derived from it. I understand the equations, but I just don't understand why it's $U_1 - U_2$.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I didn't understood too well what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is actually wrong.  The corrected one should be

$$
\ dU = - F\cos\theta ds 
$$
.

Since you're not adding/removing any energy, the force (whatever your potential energy is coming from) should increase the kinetic energy and *decrease* the potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

Take the example of gravity. Gravitational potential energy is defined as
$$U_g=-\frac{GM}{r}$$
This means that
$$U_g=-\int_{r_1}^{r_2}F_g \cos \theta dr$$
Because $F_g=mg$,
$$U_g=-\int_{r_1}^{r_2}mg \cos \theta dr$$
Integrate and you find
$$U=-mg\cos\theta \left (\left.r\right|_{r_1}^{r_2}\right)$$
and
$$U=-mg\cos\theta (r_2-r_1)$$
and if the object is going straight up and down,
$$U=-mg \Delta r$$

Comment: I get this, but in the general sense, though, why is this true? I can see it for gravity and a spring.

Comment: In one position ($r_2$), the potential energy due to a force is usually different than the potential energy in another position ($r_1$) due to that same force. The integral here shows the difference between these two locations. Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough. Does this help?